# Ошибка в Swift 'Can't perform transactions on read-only Realms.'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

опишу задачу, имеется приложение с БД Realm, в таблице имеется `favorite` с типом `Bool`, при свайпе влево есть пункт добавить в Избранное, либо если объект уже в Избранном то Удалить из избранного, в этом случае должна производиться запись в `favorite`, либо `true` либо `false`.

БД не по умолчанию, а в самом проекте, таким методом я подгружаю ее в проект:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "realm"),
    readOnly: true)

let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

При попытке произвести записть в `favorite` выскакивает ошибка `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can't perform transactions on read-only Realms.'`

Запсь производится таким образом:

```
let result = realm.objects(Chapters.self)
....
....
let favoriteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: favorite) { (action, indexPath) in
        switch self.result[indexPath.row].favorite {
    case true:
        try! realm.write {
            self.result[indexPath.row].favorite = false
        }
        print("False")
    case false:
        try! realm.write {
            self.result[indexPath.row].favorite = false
        }
        print("True")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `Realm.Configuration` с флагом `readOnly: true`.

Чего вы ожидали, если у вас стоит доступ только на чтение?

Попробуйте заменить на `readOnly: false`.

Comment: Ситуация теперь такая, на Симуляторе все Гуд, на устройстве вылет с ошибкой `"Unable to open a realm at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F74DE879-FB70-44AB-9E05-BD89193FC5EB/MyApp.app/default.realm.management'`, ругается на запись `let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)`

Comment: @АндрейСаламов на англоязычном stackoverflow уже задавался этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749793/unable-to-open-a-realm-at-path + я видел обсуждение на GitHub https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3426 .
В целом, эта ошибка гуглится. Попробуйте посмотреть решение там.